# Display data from Multidimensional array in one table

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to display data from a multidimensional array in one table, to display color, size and stock of products but without success.

[![table][1]][1]

`Tamanho` is the size, `cor` is the color and `stockfl` is the stock of the product in that color and size

I've got the follow arrays (the sizes, colors and stock are always different and some products have only one color or one size):

```
ARRAY RESULT: array(31) { [0]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XS" ["cor"]=> string(9) "ANTRACITE" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "112" } [1]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XS" ["cor"]=> string(4) "AZUL" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "145" } [2]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XS" ["cor"]=> string(12) "AZUL MARINHO" ["stockfl"]=> string(2) "83" } [3]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XS" ["cor"]=> string(14) "CINZENTO CLARO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "209" } [4]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XS" ["cor"]=> string(10) "PRETO LISO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "105" } [5]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XS" ["cor"]=> string(10) "VERDE MAÇÃ" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "128" } [6]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "S" ["cor"]=> string(9) "ANTRACITE" ["stockfl"]=> string(2) "63" } [7]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "S" ["cor"]=> string(4) "AZUL" ["stockfl"]=> string(2) "20" } [8]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "S" ["cor"]=> string(12) "AZUL MARINHO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "297" } [9]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "S" ["cor"]=> string(10) "PRETO LISO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "403" } [10]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "S" ["cor"]=> string(10) "VERDE MAÇÃ" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "108" } [11]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "S" ["cor"]=> string(8) "VERMELHO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "245" } [12]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "M" ["cor"]=> string(4) "AZUL" ["stockfl"]=> string(2) "39" } [13]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "M" ["cor"]=> string(12) "AZUL MARINHO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "555" } [14]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "M" ["cor"]=> string(10) "VERDE MAÇÃ" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "152" } [15]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "M" ["cor"]=> string(8) "VERMELHO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "836" } [16]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "L" ["cor"]=> string(14) "CINZENTO CLARO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "307" } [17]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "L" ["cor"]=> string(10) "VERDE MAÇÃ" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "136" } [18]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(1) "L" ["cor"]=> string(8) "VERMELHO" ["stockfl"]=> string(4) "1000" } [19]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XL" ["cor"]=> string(9) "ANTRACITE" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "300" } [20]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XL" ["cor"]=> string(4) "AZUL" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "164" } [21]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XL" ["cor"]=> string(12) "AZUL MARINHO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "475" } [22]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XL" ["cor"]=> string(14) "CINZENTO CLARO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "262" } [23]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XL" ["cor"]=> string(10) "VERDE MAÇÃ" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "135" } [24]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XL" ["cor"]=> string(8) "VERMELHO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "577" } [25]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(3) "XXL" ["cor"]=> string(9) "ANTRACITE" ["stockfl"]=> string(2) "52" } [26]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(3) "XXL" ["cor"]=> string(12) "AZUL MARINHO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "152" } [27]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(3) "XXL" ["cor"]=> string(10) "PRETO LISO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "272" } [28]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(3) "3XL" ["cor"]=> string(4) "AZUL" ["stockfl"]=> string(2) "97" } [29]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(3) "3XL" ["cor"]=> string(14) "CINZENTO CLARO" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "115" } [30]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(3) "3XL" ["cor"]=> string(8) "VERMELHO" ["stockfl"]=> string(2) "76" } }

ARRAY TAMANHOS: array(7) { [0]=> string(2) "XS" [1]=> string(1) "S" [2]=> string(1) "M" [3]=> string(1) "L" [4]=> string(2) "XL" [5]=> string(3) "XXL" [6]=> string(3) "3XL" }

ARRAY CORES: array(7) { ["ANTRACITE"]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(2) "XS" [1]=> string(3) "112" [2]=> string(1) "S" [3]=> string(2) "63" [4]=> string(2) "XL" [5]=> string(3) "300" [6]=> string(3) "XXL" [7]=> string(2) "52" } ["AZUL"]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(2) "XS" [1]=> string(3) "145" [2]=> string(1) "S" [3]=> string(2) "20" [4]=> string(1) "M" [5]=> string(2) "39" [6]=> string(2) "XL" [7]=> string(3) "164" [8]=> string(3) "3XL" [9]=> string(2) "97" } ["AZUL MARINHO"]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(2) "XS" [1]=> string(2) "83" [2]=> string(1) "S" [3]=> string(3) "297" [4]=> string(1) "M" [5]=> string(3) "555" [6]=> string(2) "XL" [7]=> string(3) "475" [8]=> string(3) "XXL" [9]=> string(3) "152" } ["CINZENTO CLARO"]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(2) "XS" [1]=> string(3) "209" [2]=> string(1) "L" [3]=> string(3) "307" [4]=> string(2) "XL" [5]=> string(3) "262" [6]=> string(3) "3XL" [7]=> string(3) "115" } ["PRETO LISO"]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(2) "XS" [1]=> string(3) "105" [2]=> string(1) "S" [3]=> string(3) "403" [4]=> string(3) "XXL" [5]=> string(3) "272" } ["VERDE MAÇÃ"]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(2) "XS" [1]=> string(3) "128" [2]=> string(1) "S" [3]=> string(3) "108" [4]=> string(1) "M" [5]=> string(3) "152" [6]=> string(1) "L" [7]=> string(3) "136" [8]=> string(2) "XL" [9]=> string(3) "135" } ["VERMELHO"]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(1) "S" [1]=> string(3) "245" [2]=> string(1) "M" [3]=> string(3) "836" [4]=> string(1) "L" [5]=> string(4) "1000" [6]=> string(2) "XL" [7]=> string(3) "577" [8]=> string(3) "3XL" [9]=> string(2) "76" } }


(...)
    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped ">
<thead>
<tr><th></th>
<?php
// header
foreach ($grelhas_tamanhos as $size) {
if($size == "EA" ||
    $size == "UN" ||
    $size == "CN" ||
    $size == "NO SIZE" ||
    $size == "UNI" ||
    $size == "" ||
    $size == "NO SIZE" ||
    $size == "U" ||
    $size == "ÚNICO"
    ){
        echo "<th>TU</th>";
    } else {
        echo "<th>$size</th>";
    }
}
?>
</tr></thead><tbody>
<?php
// echo each colour and its stock for each size
foreach ($grelhas_cores as $colour => $value) {
echo "<tr><td>$colour</td>";
// get stock for this colour
$result = array_values(array_filter($a, function ($v) use($colour) { return $v['cor'] == $colour; }));
foreach ($grelhas_tamanhos as $size) {
/*if (($k = array_search($size, array_column($stock, 'tamanho'))) !== false) {
echo "<td>{$stock[$k]['stockfl']}</td>";
} else {
echo '<td></td>';
}*/
}
echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

My best regards.

Comment: Always tag your questions with the language you are using otherwise they are unlikely to be seen by many people. I've added PHP to yours based on the format of your array example being the output of `var_dump`. If that is not correct please change it.

Comment: Yes, i will do it. It is PHP, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should generate a table similar to what you want.

```
$a = array(
    array('tamanho' => 'XS', 'cor' => 'ANTRACITE', 'stockfl' => 112),
    array('tamanho' => 'XS', 'cor' => 'BLUE', 'stockfl' => 145),
    array('tamanho' => 'XS', 'cor' => 'ROYAL BLUE', 'stockfl' => 83),
    array('tamanho' => 'S', 'cor' => 'BLUE', 'stockfl' => 209),
    array('tamanho' => 'S', 'cor' => 'ROYAL BLUE', 'stockfl' => 105),
    array('tamanho' => 'M', 'cor' => 'GREEN', 'stockfl' => 128),
    array('tamanho' => 'L', 'cor' => 'PINK', 'stockfl' => 128)
    );

$sizes = array('XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', '3XL');
$colours = array_unique(array_column($a, 'cor'));

?>
<table><thead><tr><th></th>
<?php
// header
foreach ($sizes as $size) {
    echo "<th>$size</th>";
}
?>
</tr></thead><tbody>
<?php
// echo each colour and its stock for each size
foreach ($colours as $colour) {
    echo "<tr><td>$colour</td>";
    // get stock for this colour
    $stock = array_values(array_filter($a, function ($v) use($colour) { return $v['cor'] == $colour; }));
    foreach ($sizes as $size) {
        if (($k = array_search($size, array_column($stock, 'tamanho'))) !== false) {
            echo "<td>{$stock[$k]['stockfl']}</td>";
        }
        else {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
</tbody></table>
```

Output:

```
<table><thead><tr><th></th>
<th>XS</th><th>S</th><th>M</th><th>L</th><th>XL</th><th>XXL</th><th>3XL</th></tr></thead><tbody>
<tr><td>ANTRACITE</td><td>112</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>BLUE</td><td>145</td><td>209</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>ROYAL BLUE</td><td>83</td><td>105</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>GREEN</td><td></td><td></td><td>128</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>PINK</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>128</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9HE7Y)

If you're using a PHP version after 5.3 but before 5.5 (when `array_column` was released) you can use `array_map` to emulate it:

```
function array_column($array, $index) {
    return array_map(function ($v) use($index) { return $v[$index]; }, $array);
}
```

Comment: first of all i want to say thanks for your precious help :) 

The only part of the code that's breaking the page is inside the comments /* */:
<?php
foreach ($grelhas_cores as $colour => $value) {
echo "<tr><td>$colour</td>";
// get stock for this colour
$result = array_values(array_filter($a, function ($v) use($colour) { return $v['cor'] == $colour; }));
foreach ($grelhas_tamanhos as $size) {
/*if (($k = array_search($size, array_column($stock, 'tamanho'))) !== false) {
echo "<td>{$stock[$k]['stockfl']}</td>";
} else {
echo '<td></td>';
}*/
}
echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>

Comment: I don't know why that part isn't working. Could you please help me? You can see two examples of the result in the attached images, i'm also printing the content of the arrays in case that help.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXbKA.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQeTD.jpg

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, here's the result of the product with several colors and sizes https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFKfy.jpg

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @user2068739 I can't debug code based on data in images. Please use the edit link under your question and add the code and data to the question as text.

Comment: Hi Nick, yeah you're right, sorry. Just edited the question and added the arrays and the table :) thank you very much

Comment: @user2068739 if I use your `ARRAY RESULT` with my code it gives the expected output table: https://3v4l.org/36uSI

Comment: Hi Nick, could it be not working because my php version it's 5.3? :(

Comment: Hi Nick, i'm going to try to put the code line by line to see why isn't working and i will give you feedback.

Comment: @user2068739 yes PHP 5.3 is your problem as `array_column` was not released until PHP 5.5. You really should upgrade - PHP5.3 hasn't been supported since [Aug 2014](https://www.php.net/eol.php)! Anyway, you can work around it by defining the function yourself using `array_map`, see my edit.

Comment: Hi Nick, i'm sorry but i didn't understand why and how to use the array_map because all the information is already in the first array "RESULT": array(31) { [0]=> array(3) { ["tamanho"]=> string(2) "XS" ["cor"]=> string(9) "ANTRACITE" ["stockfl"]=> string(3) "112" } [1]=> array(3) (...) how to display the stock in the right line and column? thanks for all your help

Comment: @user2068739 the code I posted in my original answer uses the function `array_column` which is not available in your version (5.3) of PHP. The new code that I added to the answer is a definition for an `array_column` function that you can add to the original code to work around that fact.

Comment: Hi Nick, oh okay =) that's just perfect. Just added to the code and the dynamic table is working. Thank you so much for all your help and patience in this process. I am very grateful.